# Comparing and sorting Unicode filenames

Tags: windows, delphi, filenames, tstringlist

Using Delphi 2007 and TMS components for Unicode utils and interface (upgrading to Delphi 2009 for Unicode support is not an option).

I'm storing a list of filenames in a string list (TTntStringList). It's sorted and case insensitive. The default sort routine uses CompareStringW(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, NORM_IGNORECASE, ...) to compare strings (and the same for Find). However, this is a problem because that will equate dummyss.txt with dummyß.txt (for example), but on NTFS it's perfectly legal to have those two files in the same folder, i.e. they are treated as different names.

My understanding is that on Vista and newer, the correct way to compare filenames is to use CompareStringOrdinal. Is this correct?

On pre-Vista systems, what would be the correct way? I believe it should be CompareStringW(LOCALE_INVARIANT, ...) but I'm not entirely sure.

Thanks

Comment: Note that if said sorted list is for the user to see, then you should probably use a sort that orders numbers naturally.

Comment: Indeed, like `StrCmpLogicalW()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb759947%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: StrCmpLogicalW() is no good as it also equates dummyss with dummyß

Comment: It wasn't meant as an answer to your question, just as a link to the documentation of a function that *does* this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from MSDN article [Handling Sorting in Your Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318144%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> [CompareStringOrdinal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd317762%28VS.85%29.aspx)  compares two
>   Unicode  strings to test for binary
>   equality, as opposed to linguistic
>   equality. Examples of such
>   non-linguistic strings are NTFS file
>   names, ...

CompareStringOrdinal requires Windows Vista or later.

Edit: Yes, it [seems](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=22016) that in pre-Vista Windows you can use [RtlCompareUnicodeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804321.aspx) which is used internally by CompareStringOrdinal, too, and is available since Windows NT.

Comment: What about pre-Vista? I suspect the answer is to use RtlCompareUnicodeString