# How to compare possibly alternative filenames in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, filenames

Unfortunately, directory/file names in Windows are case-insensitive.

When I compare a text (input from user) with a directory name (coming from `CFileFind`), how can I check whether they mean the same directory or not?
For example `C:\PIPPO\` and `C:\Pippo\` are the same directory, while `C:\Pippò\` is not the same (the last one has an accent).

I'm trying with:

```
if(CompareString(LOCALE_INVARIANT,NORM_IGNORECASE,q,-1,data_from_CfileFind->txt.GetBuffer(),-1)==CSTR_EQUAL)
```

(`q` is [part of] the user input)

It "kind of works", as it recognizes as same directory the case variations of Roman, Greek and Cyrillic alphabets, but it confuses `"weiß"` and `"weiss"` (and they are two different directories on my disc), so it's not reliable.

[the failing test is inspired by [Comparing and sorting Unicode filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279789/comparing-and-sorting-unicode-filenames) : I have read it, but found no suitable solution - the links appear not to work)

(I also read [Windows Invariant Culture Puzzle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061224/windows-invariant-culture-puzzle/1061324#1061324) but I'm afraid I didn't fully understand about the "cultures").

Any suggestion?

Maybe I should call `CompareString()` with different parameters?  Or is there a better, easier approach?

Please note that I don't need to sort names: I'd just like to check whether they mean the same directory (or file) to Windows or not.

By "Windows", I mean from 2000 (or at least XP) and later.

**EDIT** (sorry, the question was not well-asked the first time)

1) The path input by the user is not guaranteed to refer to an actually existing directory (in this case, of course, they are *not* the same directory).

2) I know that files and directories can be referred to by very different names, because of links (hard or soft), `subst`s, network access with different name or IP to the same computer, etc... but I'm not asking to detect all of those cases.
All I'd like to check is whether a name written by the user is a case-variation of another existing one (and thus, for example, Windows would tell me that the file already exists if I try to create one with the same name but different case).

**2nd EDIT**

This does the job (at least, in the cases that I tried):

```
if(CompareStringOrdinal(q,-1,data_from_CfileFind->txt.GetBuffer(),-1,1)==CSTR_EQUAL)
```

But `CompareStringOrdinal()` is not available in older Windows versions.
Is there any equivalent?

Comment: Can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684684/normalize-file-path-with-winapi

Answer (score 2):

The best way (that I know of) to check if two filesystem paths refer to the same item, *without* resorting to string comparisons, is to either:

1. open `HANDLE`s to the two paths using [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew), then get the unique filesystem IDs from the `HANDLE`s and compare them for equality.  On FAT and NTFS, use the combination of `dwVolumeSerialNumber` and `nFileIndex(Low|High)` from [`GetFileInformationByHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileinformationbyhandle).  On ReFS, use the combination of `VolumeSerialNumber` and `FileId` from [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx(FileIdInfo)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex) instead.  You can use [`GetVolumeInformation()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/FileAPI/nf-fileapi-getvolumeinformationa) to detect which filesystem is being used by each path.

   This approach is described in the [`BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/ns-fileapi-_by_handle_file_information) and [`FILE_ID_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/ns-winbase-_file_id_info) documentations, respectively:

   > The identifier (low and high parts) and the volume serial number uniquely identify a file on a single computer. To determine whether two open handles represent the same file, combine the identifier and the volume serial number for each file and compare them.

   > The 128-bit file identifier for the file. The file identifier and the volume serial number uniquely identify a file on a single computer. To determine whether two open handles represent the same file, combine the identifier and the volume serial number for each file and compare them.
2. a filesystem-agnostic approach is to use [`SHGetDesktopFolder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetdesktopfolder) to get the [`IShellFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder) interface for the root desktop of the Shell namespace, then resolve both paths to absolute PIDLs using the desktop's [`IShellFolder::ParseDisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-parsedisplayname) method (or use the standalone [`SHParseDisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shparsedisplayname) function), and then compare the PIDLs using the desktop's [`IShellFolder::CompareIDs()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-compareids) method.

Comment: I'm afraid I misled you with the question (please see the "EDIT"). However, `CreateFile()` does'n work on some directories (like `C:\System Volume Information` - but I cannot create e.g. a `C:\System VOLUME Information` because it would be the same directory...).
I'll try method 2. or somehing simpler.
Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Start by calling [GetFullPathName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfullpathnamea) on each path, then do [GetLongPathName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamea) and finally do a case-insensitive comparison on the results.

`GetFullPathName` will give a fully qualified path to each file. `GetLongPathName` then gets the real name of each component of that path, so if somebody used a Windows 95/98 style short name for a file/directory, that wont confuse things.

Comment: "and finally do a case-insensitive comparison on the results"  is exactly my problem. How do I perform it? I tried with `CompareString(LOCALE_INVARIANT,NORM_IGNORECASE ....` but it confuses `weiß` and `weiss` that are two different directories.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it appears to work:

1) At the start of the program, call a `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");`

2) Then compare the strings with `if(!data_from_CfileFind->txt.CompareNoCase(q))` (that calls `_wcsicmp` that calls `_wcsicmp_l`)